# Ansible multiple commands to a file

Tags: ansible

You can see bellow how it looks like my Ansible Script.

My question is what i need to change to get output from multiple commands to a file.The problem is that i get output only from the first command.

I have 200 vrf,do i really need to make multiple tasks fior multiple commands,or there is another solution for it.

I would highly appreciate any response.

```yaml
---
- name: PING_TenGig_Ethernet_VRFs
  hosts: fr1.s05
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: run multiple commands on remote nodes
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - show bgp vrf Mgmt-intf
          - show bgp vrf cha-00 all summary
          - show bgp vrf cha-001 all summary
          - show bgp vrf cha-002 all summary
          - show bgp vrf cha-00303 all summary

      register: print_output

    -  debug: var=print_output.stdout_lines

    - name: save output to a file
      copy: content="{{ print_output.stdout[0] }}" dest="./output/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/ios_command_module.html), the result of your `run multiple commands on remote nodes` block is an array. You're writing only the first item of that array with `{{ print_output.stdout[0] }}`. The `[0]` here is the pointer to the first element of the array. Try removing it and see if the result fits your needs.

**UPD**: Use this to write several strings into a file:

```yaml
- name: save output to a file
  lineinfile:
    create: yes
    line: "{{item}}"
    path: ./output/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt
  with_items: "{{ print_output.stdout }}"
```

Comment: As first of all Thank you but for your answer. When i removed [ 0 ]that resolved one issue but brought me to another one.It seem to be that i have desired output from multiple commands now, but the problem is that output format is now changed to horizotal lines what is very uncovininet to read.If i know how to change it then that would be solution

Comment: @user28132 I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much .That is a real solution,i get all my commands to a file now.